# ImportError: cannot import name extensions

Tags: scrapy

$ scrapy version: 0.14 $

$ file: settings.py $

```
EXTENSIONS = { 'myproject.extensions.MySQLManager': 500 }
```

$ file: pipeline.py $

```
# -- coding: utf-8 -- 
# Define your item pipelines here # 
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting 
# See: doc.scrapy.org/topics/item-pipeline.html 

from scrapy.project import extensions
from urlparse import urlparse 
import re 
class MySQLStorePipeline(object): 
    def process_item(self, item, spider): 
        if self.is_allowed_domain(item['url'], spider) is True: 
            MySQLManager.cursor... #cannot load MySQLManager
```

ImportError: cannot import name extensions.
i can't find extensions class in /scrapy/project.py

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to import but as far as I understand, if you want to "import" an extension, you should add some lines to your settings.py file in your scrapy project.

Example:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.contrib.corestats.CoreStats': 500,
    'scrapy.webservice.WebService': 500,
    'scrapy.myextension.myextension': 500,
}
```

You can read more about Scrapy extensions [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html)